# onItemContextMenu and button created programatically problem

Tags: java, android

I would like if anybody could help to solve the problem, that I'm trying to fix in my code. I'm really despearte!

I would like to know if it's possible get from the contextmenu, all the information of the button that I created, and use the setText function later.

Ok, first of all I create a tablerow with some buttons (like a soundboard application)

```
for (int j = 0 ; index > 0 && j < 2 ; j++) {
    final CustomToggleButton tagB = new CustomToggleButton(this);
    tagB.setId(index);
    ...
    ...
    registerForContextMenu(tagB);
    tagB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
               ....
          }
          ...
    }
}
```

Secondly, I let every button an "edit" option for changing the text in it:

```
@Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,  ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
     AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Opciones de la etiqueta");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");
 }
```

Finally I use onContextItemSelected for creating an EditText Alert and let the possibility of introduce the new text.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit") {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setTitle("Nombre del tag");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                Log.v(null, "nombre del tag nuevo: "+value);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int button_id = item.getItemId();   // BUTTON ID? 
                //CustomToggleButton tagB = (CustomToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button_id);//DOESN'T WORK!!
                //CustomToggleButton tagB = (CustomToggleButton) findViewById(button_id); // NEITHER DOESN'T WORK!!
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }
    else return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

The problem is that I can't use its id from R.java, because I have created the button programatically...

Is there any solution for this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the ID of the button.  You need to reference the Button object you created via code.

**Edit:**  Just define the button object with the scope you require.  You probably need class scope.  You could use an array or list if you would like.  Depending on how many buttons you have, that may be the way to go.

Comment: The best option I think, shall I keep the buttons in an array and get the position of it?

Comment: Thank you, I've used an array of buttons, and I get the button by its ID. Thank you so much!!!